# How to remove warning when I put bootstrap to styles.css Angular?

Tags: angular

I put `Bootstrap v4.1.0` to `styles.css` in Angular Project. And Then I get this warning at the console.

> [WDS] Warnings while compiling.
>
> ./src/styles.css
>   (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css)
>   Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
>   Warning
>
> (9902:3) Replace text-decoration-skip: ink to
>   text-decoration-skip-ink: auto, because spec had been changed

Is there anyway to remove this warning?

Thanks,

Comment: Did my answere solved your issue??

Comment: No. I don't think this is a root cause. You just move the bootstrap from `style.css` to put in `angular.json` only. Very appreciated your help @SavanPadaliya

Answer (score 0):

In angular if you want to link bootstrap link then you should add it in `angular.json`.
Otherwise it will show this warning. Best way to solve this is as follow:

Step 1: Install bootstrap by `npm i bootstrap@4`

Step 2: Open `angular.json`

Step 3: Write down link in styles section in `angular.json` as below.

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar in my project lately. There was such a warning next to it:

```
autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust.
```

I added this to my package.json and both warnings has gone:

```
"resolutions": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31982311)